# Vue.js не правильно работает splice

Tags: vue.js, frontend

учу vue.js, столкнулся с проблемой. Отображаю список из базы, при редактировании записи заменяется последняя запись в списке, и в браузере в консоле вылетает вылетает ошибка:

```
vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '62'. This may cause an 
update error.
found in
---> <BearList>
         <Root>
```

Пытаюсь заменить запись с помощью vm.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
[Пример с ru.vuejs.org](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html), мне кажется, что я где-то недогоняю с v-key:

метод сохранения изменений:

```
 methods: {
    save() {
        var bear = {
            title: this.title,
            body: this.body,
            id: this.id
        };
        if (this.id) {
            bearsApi.update(bear).then(result =>
                result.json().then(data => {
                    var index = this.id;
                    this.bears.splice(findIndex(this.id,this.bears),1,data);
                    this.title = '';
                    this.body = '';
                    this.id = '';
                }))
        } else {
            bearsApi.save({}, bear).then(result =>
                result.json().then(data => {
                    this.bears.push(bear);
                    this.title = '';
                    this.body = '';
                }))
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Формирование списка:

```
    template:
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3" v-for="bear in bears" :key="bear.id">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
                   <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ bear.title }}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ bear.body }}</p>
                        <span>{{ bear. id }}</span>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
                          @click="edit(bear)">Изменить</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
```

findIndex :

```
function findIndex(id, bears) {
let i = 0;
bears.forEach(function (element) {
    if (element.id === id) {
        console.log(i);
       return i;
    }
    i++;
})
    return -1;
}
```

[Файл main.js целиком](https://gist.github.com/nOy39/661725130b88e3c10b084865b329c100)

Подскажите в чём косяк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе ошибка явно указывает, что в атрибуте `:key` есть дублирующее значение.
Измени рендер списка таким образом:

```
<div class="col-3" v-for="(bear, index) in bears" :key="index">
```

**upd:**
Моменты, над которыми надо поработать:

1. [Однонаправленный поток данных](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). Это значит, что ты изменяешь только ЛОКАЛЬНЫЕ данные компонента, не изменяя данные, переданные в `props`:

   ```
   Vue.component('bear-list', {
     props: ['bears'], // bearsApi именно тут не нужен
     data: function () {
       return {
           localBears: []
       }
     },
     created: function(){
       this.localBears = this.bears.slice()
     }
   });
   ```
2. При обработке событий в списке передавай сам объект и его индекс в списке

   ```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="edit(bear, index)">Изменить</button>
   ```

и метод в `methods`:

```
    edit: function(bear, index){
      // какие-то действия
      this.localBears.splice(index, 1, Object.assign({},this.localBears[index], {param:value}))
    }
```

Comment: спасибо, за подсказку ошибка в консоле браузера исчезла, но запись все равно меняется последняя...

Comment: теперь увидел проблему твою))

Comment: Спасибо за помощь с индексом) проблема была в его вычислении

Comment: function findIndex(id, bears) {
       let i = 0;
       let index = 0;
      bears.forEach(function (element) {
          if (element.id === id) {
              console.log(i);
             index = i;
          }
         i++;
      })
      return index;
    }

Comment: Обновил ответ, индекс ты можешь передавать непосредственно в метод и не надо будет его вычислять. все просто)

Comment: ну до этого я еще не дошёл)))

Comment: тогда просто сначала прочти руководство до раздела **Инструментарий**. По пути можешь делать те примеры, которые там есть (не больше). Как прочтешь, немного сложится картинка что к чему и какие возможности есть, потом в зависимости от задач будешь перечитывать каждый раздел по нескольку раз.