# Как исправить ошибку vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '80'. This may cause an update error

Tags: vue.js, rest, spring-boot

Пытаюсь реализовать фронт на JS для REST приложения на Spring
Приложение - список дел. Добавление дел проходит нормально. Например, я добавил 2 дела:
[image: Добавление двух дел]

При попытке отредактировать дело в форму передаются значения полей с именем, описанием, автором. Допустим, мы что-то поменяли, нажали кнопку "Сохранить", то мы видим 2 разных дела, но у них, почему-то, одинаковый ID!
[image: Задвоение ID]

Лог ошибки в консоли браузера:

```
 vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '82'. This may cause an update error.

found in

---> <TaskList>
       <Root>
warn    @   vue.js:634
checkDuplicateKeys  @   vue.js:6241
updateChildren  @   vue.js:6179
patchVnode  @   vue.js:6314
updateChildren  @   vue.js:6188
patchVnode  @   vue.js:6314
updateChildren  @   vue.js:6188
patchVnode  @   vue.js:6314
patch   @   vue.js:6475
Vue._update @   vue.js:3949
updateComponent @   vue.js:4067
get @   vue.js:4478
run @   vue.js:4553
flushSchedulerQueue @   vue.js:4311
(anonymous) @   vue.js:1989
flushCallbacks  @   vue.js:1915
Promise.then (async)        
timerFunc   @   vue.js:1942
nextTick    @   vue.js:1999
queueWatcher    @   vue.js:4403
update  @   vue.js:4543
notify  @   vue.js:745
mutator @   vue.js:897
(anonymous) @   main.js:58
Promise.then (async)        
e.then  @   vue-resource@1.5.1:7
(anonymous) @   main.js:56
Promise.then (async)        
e.then  @   vue-resource@1.5.1:7
save    @   main.js:55
invokeWithErrorHandling @   vue.js:1863
invoker @   vue.js:2188
original._wrapper   @   vue.js:7547
```

Код Контроллера ниже:

```
    package ru.skillbox.ifomkin.todolist.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import ru.skillbox.ifomkin.todolist.entity.Task;
import ru.skillbox.ifomkin.todolist.service.TaskService;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("task")
public class RestConroller {

    @Autowired
    private TaskService service;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Task> getAll() {
        return service.getAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("{id}")
    public Task taskById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return service.findById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Task add(@RequestBody Task newTask) {
        newTask.setCreationDate(new Date());
        service.save(newTask);
        return newTask;
    }

    @PutMapping("{id}")
    public Task update(@RequestBody Task task, @PathVariable int id) {
        return service.updateTask(task, id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable int id) {
        service.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Код main.js:

```
function getIndex(list, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].id === id) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

var taskApi = Vue.resource('/task{/id}');

Vue.component('task-form', { // Форма задания
    props: ['tasks', 'taskAttr'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            description: '',
            author: ''
        }
    },
    watch: {
        taskAttr: function (newVal, oldVal) {
            this.id = newVal.id;
            this.name = newVal.name;
            this.description = newVal.description;
            this.author = newVal.author;
        }
    },
    template:
        '<form><div class="form-row">' +
        '<div class="col">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" v-model="name" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Описание" v-model="description" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Автор" v-model="author" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="col">' +
        '<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Сохранить" v-on:click="save" />' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div></form>',
    methods: {
        save: function () {
            var task = {
                name: this.name,
                description: this.description,
                author: this.author
            };

            if (this.id) {
                taskApi.update({id: this.id}, task).then(result =>
                    result.json().then(data => {
                        var index = getIndex(this.tasks, data.id);
                        this.tasks.splice(index, 1, data);
                        this.name = ''; //Обнуляем поля
                        this.description = '';
                        this.author = '';
                    })
                )
            } else {
                taskApi.save({}, task).then(result =>
                    result.json().then(data => {
                        this.tasks.push(data);
                        this.name = ''; //Обнуляем поля
                        this.description = '';
                        this.author = '';
                    })
                )
            }
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('task-row', { //Строчка с заданием
    props: ['task', 'editTask', 'tasks'],
    template:
        '<tr>' +
        '<th scope="row>">{{task.id}}</th>' +
        '<td>{{task.name}}</td>' +
        '<td>{{task.description}}</td>' +
        '<td>{{task.author}}</td>' +
        '<td>{{task.creationDate}}</td>' +
        '<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Изменить" v-on:click="edit"/></td>' +
        '<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Удалить" v-on:click="del"/></td>' +
        '</tr>',
    methods: {
        edit: function () {
            this.editTask(this.task);
        },
        del: function () {
            taskApi.remove({id: this.task.id}).then(result => {
                if (result.ok) {
                    this.tasks.splice(this.tasks.indexOf(this.task), 1)
                }
            })
        }
    }
});

Vue.component('task-table-header', { //Временная шапка таблицы
    template: '' +
        '' +
        '    <thead class="thead-dark">\n' +
        '<br>' +
        '    <tr>' +
        '        <th scope="col">ID</th>' +
        '        <th scope="col">Имя</th>' +
        '        <th scope="col">Описание</th>' +
        '        <th scope="col">Автор</th>' +
        '        <th scope="col">Дата создания</th>' +
        '        <th scope="col" colspan="2">Редактирование</th>' +
        '    </tr>' +
        '    </thead>'
});

Vue.component('task-list', { //Список заданий с циклом
    props: ['tasks'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            task: null
        }
    },
    template: '' +
        '<div>' +
        '<task-form :tasks="tasks" :taskAttr="task"/>' +
        '<table class="table">' +
        '<task-table-header />' +
        '<tbody>' +
        '<task-row v-for="task in tasks" v-bind:key="task.id" :tasks="tasks" :task="task" :editTask="editTask"/>' +
        '</tbody>' +
        '</table>' +
        '</div>',
    created: function () {
        taskApi.get().then(result =>
            result.json().then(data =>
                data.forEach(task => this.tasks.push(task))
            ))
    },
    methods: {
        editTask: function (task) {
            this.task = task;
        }
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<task-list :tasks="tasks"/>',
    data: {
        tasks: []
    }
})
```

Код TaskService:

```
package ru.skillbox.ifomkin.todolist.service;

import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import ru.skillbox.ifomkin.todolist.entity.Task;
import ru.skillbox.ifomkin.todolist.repository.TaskRepository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class TaskService {
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository repository;

    public List<Task> getAll() {
        Iterable<Task> taskIterable = repository.findAll();
        List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Task task : taskIterable) {
            tasks.add(task);
        }
        return tasks;
    }

    public Task updateTask(Task task, int id) {
        Task currentTask = repository.findById(id);
        currentTask.setAuthor(task.getAuthor());
        currentTask.setDescription(task.getDescription());
        currentTask.setName(task.getName());
        repository.save(currentTask);
        return currentTask;
    }

    public Task findById(int id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }

    public void save(Task task) {
        repository.save(task);
    }

    public void deleteById(int id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Код index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ToDoList</title>
    <!--    Vue JS      -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <!--    Vue resource    -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.5.1"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <a th:href="@{/}" class="navbar-brand" th:text="ToDoList"/>
    <p th:text="'A simple time management application'"/>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <div>
        <a href="thymeleaf">Go to Thymeleaf page</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Что надо поправить, чтобы этого бага не было?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, проблема была с вычислением индекса

Функция поиска должна выглядеть так:

```
    function getIndex(tasks, id) {
    let i = 0;
    let index = 0;
    tasks.forEach(function (element) {
        if (element.id === id) {
            index = i;
        }
        i++;
    })
    return index;
}
```

Ответ нашёл [Вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849988/vue-js-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-splice)